# What is Shoulda's route matcher for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

According to [the shoulda page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers),

> ## ActionController Matchers
>
> - **route** tests your routes.

And I'm just not sure what it's used for. Especially in an isolated **controller** unit spec. Why is this in a controller spec? What's the relevance? Shouldn't this simply be in its own routes spec? And yet on the shoulda page this matcher is listed as an ActionController Matcher...

Or is ActionController in charge of routes so uses this matcher?

If I should be using this matcher in my controller specs, could I have an example to show how should I go about using this?

Comment: you're changing the subject of the spec - most of shoulda-matchers' controller matchers will break horribly if you do that. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/90

Comment: What should the subject be. The controller? And could you explain a bit what it actually does?

Comment: the subject should be left as the default, which for a controller spec is the controller itself.

Comment: I'm getting `Failure/Error: controller.should route(:get, '/posts/1').to(action: :show, id: 1)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'should' for #<FoldersController:0x007fbed9516630>`

Comment: leave the subject off entirely. `it { should route(whatever).to(whatever) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is shoulda-matchers' `route` matcher an `ActionController` matcher?**

shoulda-matchers' `route` matcher is an `ActionController` matcher simply because its subject can be a controller. You can specify `:controller` yourself, in which case the subject doesn't matter:

```
describe 'Routing' do
  it { is_expected.to route(:get, '/posts/1').to(controller: :posts, action: :show, id: 1) }
end
```

or you can let it infer `:controller` for you:

```
describe PostsController do
  it { is_expected.to route(:get, '/posts/1').to(action: :show, id: 1) }
end
```

In the latter case, all `route` does with the subject (`PostsController`) is call `.controller_name` on it. But it uses the controller, so it's an `ActionController` matcher.

**Is `route` for controller specs or routing specs?**

Routing is a completely separate layer of Rails from controllers, so RSpec has separate controller and routing specs, and that's how I write them. But I do use shoulda-matchers, and I like to not have to type `controller:`, so I make the subjects of my routing specs controllers as in the second example above.

If you write your routing specs that way the subjects of your controller and routing specs are the same, so you might find it convenient to put your routing examples in your controller spec files. It would make it easier to keep your controller and routing specs in sync as you add or remove controller actions. I wouldn't argue against that. I would keep in mind, though, that the controller isn't really the subject of the routing specs; it's just saving you typing.

[The shoulda-matchers rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/file/lib/shoulda/matchers/action_controller/route_matcher.rb) suggests both possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Dave, cleared that up. I think I'm going to put these expectations in my `spec/routing/*` directory. That's what you do, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do.